# how to switch to unity software center from gnome software center in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: launcher, ubuntu-gnome

how to switch to unity software center from gnome software center in ubuntu 16.04 ?

I don't like gnome software center, unity was better.

Comment: No need to switch, just install the old one: *sudo apt install software-center*. Be aware it is no longer developed and at one point it may stop working or may break something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Unity Software Center`.  Ubuntu 16.04 uses `gnome-software` (alias `ubuntu-software`).  You could install `software-center`:

```
$ sudo apt install software-center
```

Then you will have an option of running `ubuntu-software` or `software-center` when you type `software center` in the Ubuntu dash.

`software-center` was the default installation before `Ubuntu 16.04`.  You can choose which will load by default from the file browse by right clicking on a `*.deb' file and choosing your preference for opening a the`*.deb` package.

From your file browser:

> <kbd>Right Click</kbd> [**the *.deb file]** -> <kbd>click</kbd> **Properties** -> <kbd>click</kbd> **Open With** -> <kbd>select</kbd> **[Your Software Installer choice]** -> <kbd>click</kbd> **Set as Default**